# How to upgrade a XML file in Android

Tags: android, xml

I would know if is it possible upgrade a XML file in an Android application.

I have a XML file in /raw/ ,  i want implement a function (like "check update") that controls if the XML is it older than another file in a server, the XML file contain a version number such as Version="1.0".

In this case, if the XML version of the file in the server is it  >  than 1.0 i want download this file and replace the XML file in /RAW/

How i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. What you can do however is copy the XML from `res/raw` in your app data folder at first launch, then work on this one, on which you have write access.

Comment: I dont understand only 1 thing. In which folder can i put the data so that they can be modified at a later time ? what are the " app data folders " ?

Comment: Android allows you to store data in a folder specific to your application. It's, also, private (unless the device is rooted, then it's not guaranteed anymore). See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal